# Deployment of Custom Timer job in Sharepoint 2010 causes error

Tags: sharepoint-timer-job

I am creating Timer Job in Sharepoint 2010. 
When I try to deploy the solution I get the following error :

Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I am not able to figure out the cause of this error. 
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably issue is related with account you are using to deploy solution. Be sure you are using a farm admin account to add or deploy solutions.

Cheers.